# Android System kill App Activity recreation

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

If i have on my Nexus 5 more than 18 Apps open, then my app disappears from the app history and is killed from the system. I start my app from the springboard (i dont know how it called by android) and my splashscreen activity is started. After this my mainactivity is started but android wants to recreate the mainactivity (Bundle is not null). The activity have a viewpager and some menu items, but the recreation takes a long time and the user see a blank activity with a actionbar.

What is the best practice to recreate a activity?
I find only simple examples with one textview and one edittext. But my activity is complex with fragments inside the viewpager and some other controls.

And yes i have read this article http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best practice to recreate a activity?

Do it faster.

> But my activity is complex with fragments inside the viewpager and some other controls.

Use Traceview to determine where your performance problem lies.